# rc.local is not running on raspberry pi's startup

Tags: c, linux, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I'm trying to run a simple C code when the pi boots, so I followed the steps on the documentation (https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md), but when I start it, it shows this error:

```
Failed to start etc/rc.local compatibility.
See 'systemctl status rc-local.service' for details.
```

I do as it says and I receive this:

```
rc-local.service - /etc/rc.local Compatibility
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service; static)
Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service.d
         ttyoutput.conf
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2015-12-08 10:44:23 UTC; 2min 18s ago
Process: 451 ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start (code=exit, status=203/EXEC)
```

My rc.local file looks like this:

```
./home/pi/server-starter &

exit 0
```

Can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you `systemctl enable rc-local.service`? What happens when you `systemctl start rc-local.service` when it's already running? (Does that change the output of `systemctl status rc-local.service`?)

Comment: Yes, and when I do it, it shows the message I've put here, after the 'I do as it says...'

Answer (score 1):

You have to refer to your script using an absolute path.

```
/home/pi/server-starter &
```

Notice the absence of the `.` in comparison to your solution.

Also, you may have to add a reference to the shell right at the beginning of your rc.local.

```
#!/bin/sh -e
/home/pi/server-starter &
exit 0
```

Comment: I followed your suggestion, but it keeps showing the same error on Pi's startup.

Comment: Does executing `sh /home/pi/server-starter` work correctly?

Comment: I executed it here and it showed the error  
`/home/pi/server-starter: 1: /home/pi/server-starter: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")`  

Here's my full code:  

`#include <stdio.h>   


#include <unistd.h>   


int main(int argc, char **argv){   

      const char *fname = "farm-info";   

      if (access(fname, F_OK) != -1){   

            return 1;   

      }else{   

            system("node /home/pi/app.js");   

      }   

      return 0;  

}`

Comment: This is not a script that can be started using the shell (sh) but looks like a C(++).program which has to be compiled first.

Comment: I know it's not a script, that's why I was trying to put the command inside the rc.local file with the "." . It's already compiled, and when I run `./home/pi/server-starter` on the command line, it works as it is supposed to.

Comment: `./home/pi/server-starter` should only work if you are in the root folder `/` with your shell. If you are somewhere else (probably your home directory `/home/pi`), you may have another/different `server-starter` file somewhere (e.g. `/home/pi/home/pi/server-starter`).

Answer (score 1):

to run a script shell "in a script shell" use this :

```
sh -c /absolute/path/to/script;
```

to run this script in background use this :

```
sh -c /absolute/path/to/script &;
```

Don't forget `exit 0` at the end of the file